# Errno 2 No such file or directory: 'credentials.json'

Tags: python-3.x

python 3.6

still in the process of learning python, using this code from a public source but running into this issue:

"  [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'credentials.json'  "
File "C:\Users\BLINDEYE\Desktop\GeminiBots\main.py",

```
with open("credentials.json", "r") as f:
    credentials = json.loads(f.read())
CONSUMER_KEY = credentials['CONSUMER_KEY']
CONSUMER_SECRET = credentials['CONSUMER_SECRET']
ACCESS_TOKEN = credentials['ACCESS_TOKEN']
ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET = credentials['ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET']
```

not sure if im just in the wrong directory or what but the requirements.json is stored in
C:\Users\BLINDEYE\Desktop\GeminiBots

any help would be appreciated

Comment: welcome to StackOverflow! please add more information to your question, specially  what you try to accomplish so more people can understand you and help ;)

Comment: Do you mean requirements.json or credentials.json ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think littlecute means try this:

```
 with open("C:/Users/BLINDEYE/Desktop/GeminiBots/credentials.json", "r") as f:
```

Answer (score 0):

C:\Users\BLINDEYE\Desktop\GeminiBots\credentials.json？
Is this the path?You can try this absolute path above.